# Android app doen't save data in WAMP database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, wamp

The user must add a marker by tapping the map. My goal is to send the Name, Category, Latitude and Longitude to a SQL database. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOsZHuu8Qog. The app works, it even gets a `toast` that the *"Registration Succeeded!"* but the database **is still empty**.

***Also***, maybe there is something wrong with the communication between my app and the WampServer. I wonder if the connection URL is correct. I found on the Internet that the ***default WAMP localhost IP*** is 10.0.2.2 or it can work with my PC's local IP. Both of them didn't work.

See the code:

**AddShopActivity.java**

```
public class AddShopActivity extends MainScreen implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

String Name, Category, Latitude, Longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_shop);
    initMap();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.eidoskatastimatos, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

LocationRequest mLocationsRequest;

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationsRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationsRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationsRequest.setInterval(5000);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationsRequest, this);


    mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            EditText shop_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
            Spinner shop_category = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                                       .position(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
                                       .draggable(true)
                                       .title(shop_name.getText().toString())
                                       .snippet(shop_category.getSelectedItem().toString());


            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);

            mGoogleMap.clear();
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);

            Name = shop_name.getText().toString();
            Category = shop_category.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
            Longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);
        }
    });

}

public void shopReg(View view)
{
    String method = "save";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method, Name, Category, Latitude, Longitude);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't get current location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 16);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(update);
    }

}
}
```

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/shop/register.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("save"))
    {
        String Name = params[1];
        String Category = params[2];
        String Latitude = params[3];
        String Longitude = params[4];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("Name", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(Name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("Category", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(Category,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("Latitude", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(Latitude,"UTF-8")+"&"+
            URLEncoder.encode("Longitude", "UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(Longitude,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Το κατάστημα προστέθηκε!";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**init.php**

```
<?php
$db_name="shops";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="";
$server_name="localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
require"init.php";

$shop_name=$_POST["Name"];
$shop_category=$_POST["Category"];
$shop_latitude=$_POST["Latitude"];
$shop_longitude=$_POST["Longitude"];

$sql_query="insert into shop_info values('$shop_name','$shop_category','$shop_latitude','$shop_longidude');";

?>
```

Comment: Hi, seems like you're having multiple issues here.
First of all check whether both the mobile app and the hosted WampServer are on the same network. Then use a tool similar to Postman to verify that your register endpoint works. After clarifying both, let's try to solve the mobile app issue.

Comment: @Ruchira Randana I use the default Emulator of android Studio. About the "Postman" tool, what is that? I 've never used it. Where can I find it?

Comment: Postman is and add-on for Chrome. You can use it to test your web service. There are many other similar tools such as CURL.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: @RuchiraRandana hello again. I was away for some days due to personal problems but I'm back. Can you please guide me on how to use the Postman as you proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the backend (php) code is just what you provide in this example, you never actually execute any code that saves anything, so no wonder your db is empty.

What your code does now:

- Prepares a connection in `init.php`
- Prepares a string representation of an SQL query by inserting user supplied data in the string in `register.php` (*ouch, read below*)

What is missing:

- Executing the query to actually do something with the data, i.e. `mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);`
- Learning about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- Implementing one of the proper ways to avoid SQL injection in a PHP script (i.e. [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php))
- (Optional but recommended) Use the modern [PDO interface](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) to access the database.

As a general suggestion, you should aim to break down complex code to small testable parts that you can verify they work.

For example had you tried to call `register.php` with actual values instead of those coming from `POST` data you would quickly see that it doesn't save anything, instead of looking at IPs, connections or your android code. The comment you got was in that direction - forget about your android app and try to verify the backend saves a request once it comes in.

Comment: It worked! `mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query)` in `register.php`. Thanks!